# Are all continuous functions computable (for a peculiar definition of continuity)?

Tags: continuity, computability

A (partial) function $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ is *continuous* if, for every [recursively enumerable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computably_enumerable) (henceforth, $RE$) set $S$, the preimage $f^{-1}(S)=\{x\in\mathbb{N}\mid f(x)\in S\}$ is also $RE$. This isn't a standard definition of continuity - although it is very obviously inspired by the topological definition - and is what we referred to in the title as being peculiar.

A (partial) function $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ is *computable* if it can be realized in some Turing-complete model of computation (for example, if there exists a Turing machine s.t., with input $n$, halts with $f(n)$ as the result, or loops forever if $f$ is not defined for the input).

It is a simple exercise to check that every computable function is continuous (given a computable function $f$ and a $RE$ set $S$, one can enumerate the preimage by simply enumerating all naturals $n$, computing $f(n)$ and checking whether $f(n)\in S$ or not), but what about the converse? **Given any  continuous function, is it possible to show that it is also computable?**

I believe there should be a simple cardinality argument that answers the question in the negative, but i haven't been able to formulate it. A concrete example would be preferred, of course, but beggars can't be choosers.

Comment: D'oh! Title should now be correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your suspicion is right - continuity in your sense, which I'll call "ce-continuity" to avoid confusion, **does not imply** computability. For example, we have the following:

> There is a total injective function $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ such that for every c.e. $X$ either $f^{-1}(X)$ is finite or $f^{-1}(X)$ is cofinite.

Call such a function "wild." Every wild function is trivially ce-continuous, but no such function can be computable. This is because if $f$ were wild and computable, the set $E=\{f(2n):n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ would have to be c.e., but $E$ has bi-infinite $f$-preimage.

One way to construct a wild function is to first construct a **cohesive set**: a set $X\subseteq\mathbb{N}$ is cohesive iff $X$ is infinite and for every c.e. set $A$, either $X\cap A$ is finite or $X\cap(\mathbb{N}\setminus A)$ is finite. That is, a cohesive set either "mostly lies in" or "mostly avoids" each c.e. set. It's a good exercise to show that if $X$ is cohesive then the *principal function* of $X$ (= send $n$ to the $n$th element of $X$ in increasing order) is wild. Here's a sketch of how to construct a cohesive set; filling in the details is a good exercise:

Let $(W_e)_{e\in\mathbb{N}}$ be some enumeration of the c.e. sets. Define new sets $A_e$ recursively as follows: we let $$A_e=(\bigcap_{i<e}A_i)\cap W_e$$ if that intersection is infinite and let $$A_e=(\bigcap_{i<e}A_i)\setminus W_e$$ otherwise. It's easy to check that $A_0\supseteq A_1\supseteq ...$ and that each $A_e$ is infinite. Now we can't just take the intersection of the $A_i$s since that might be finite (or even empty!), but we can do something "intersection-flavored:" recursively let $a_e$ be the least element of $A_e$ greater than every $a_i$ with $i<e$ (this is well-defined since the $A_e$s are infinite). The set $$X=\{a_e:e\in\mathbb{N}\}$$ can then be shown to be cohesive. If you've seen the notion of *diagonal intersections* in set theory, this is a similar idea.

---

One way we can strengthen ce-continuity is by adding a uniformity assumption: say that a (total, for simplicity) function $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ is **uniformly ce-continuous** iff there is some computable function $h$ such that for each $e$ we have $f^{-1}(W_e)=W_{h(e)}$. Clearly every uniformly ce-continuous function is ce-continuous and every computable function is uniformly ce-continuous, so this is genuinely a good refinement of the original notion.

Once we make this modification, we do in fact "close the gap:" the uniformly ce-continuous functions are exactly the computable functions. To see this, suppose $f$ is uniformly ce-continuous via $h$ and we want to compute $f(n)$. In parallel we'll enumerate each $W_{h(i)}$; eventually for some $i$ we see $n$ enter $W_{h(i)}$, and at that point we know that $f(n)=i$.

In general, there are lots of seemingly-nice notions which are actually pretty badly behaved **until we add a uniformity condition to them**.

Comment: Thank you so much for the wonderful answer! I'll be sure to work through the exercises, as that cohesive set makes for an example of non-c.e. set i absolutely did not know about.

Comment: Also, for posterity's sake (i don't think you have to edit your answer!), i'd like to record the reasoning i went through in order to understand why $E$ has a bi-infinite $f$-preimage. Because $f$ is total and injective, the $f$-preimages of $E$ and its obvious analog $F=\{f(1+2n):n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ split the natural numbers in two infinite (due to injectivity and totality) and disjoint (due to injectivity) halves. So neither preimage can be finite (they're infinite), nor can they be cofinite (the intersection of a cofinite set and any other infinite one isn't disjoint); they are bi-infinite.